# Can XCTest (the built in unit tests) be used with NSURLConnection's sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:?

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection, block, objective-c-blocks, weak-references

I created a Server class with methods that use NSURLConnection's sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler: method.

I set completionHandler: to a block that should run when the server returns, and in that block I try to use XCTAssertTrue but get the warning:

```
"Capturing 'self' strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle"
```

Now I've seen this warning before when trying to use 'self' in a block (and am guessing both problems are related?).  Usually to silence these warnings you declare variables outside of the block or queue with __block or __weak.  Then you can read from those variables in the block or assign a value to them and retrieve the value assigned inside of the block from outside of the block.  So instead of just using self or self.player in one of my classes I would do this:

```
__weak FancyViewController *weakSelf = self;
__block Player *blockPlayer = self.player;
```

and use weakSelf and blockPlayer inside of the block to get rid of the errors.

What about XCTest methods?  Can they be used in blocks or queues?